# pandas dataframe - set columns type without SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and I want to set the type of a few columns to be float. However, I tried a few ways and **they all gave me the SettingWithCopyWarning**:

```
df[column_list] = df[column_list].astype(float)
df.loc[:, column_list] = df[column_list].astype(float)
df[column_list] = df[column_list].astype(float)
dfdf.loc[:, column_list] = df.loc[:, column_list].astype(float)
```

The error was either:

1. A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

or if I used .loc:

2. A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

What's more weird is, **I can't replicate the error with an example dataframe** as

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,5], [4,6,9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
cols = ['A', 'B']
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
```

does not give the warning.

The original dataframe was about 100 columns x 50000 rows but they were just a bunch of numbers  (some of which are large but this shouldn't be the problem?) plus some np.nan

Comment: The reason you can't replicate it with the sample frame is because the Frame became a copy of a slice at some point _before_ the line you've shown.

Comment: @HenryEcker You are absolutely right! I found the relevant line and it's all fixed now. Thanks a lot